# Error en conexion al intentar insertas datos mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando insertar usuarios en una base de datos pero a la hora de darle al botón enviar me aparece el siguiente problema:
[image: 1]

La linea 8 esta marcada entre asteriscos:

```
include_once "app/Usuario.inc.php";
include_once "app/ValidadorRegistro.inc.php";

if (isset($_POST["enviar"])){
    Conexion :: abrir_conexion();

    $validador = new ValidadorRegistro($_POST["nombre"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["clave1"], $_POST["clave2"]);

    if ($validador -> registro_valido()){
        $usuario = new Usuario('', $validador-> obtener_nombre(), $validador -> obtener_email(), $validador -> obtener_clave(), '', '');
        $usuario_insertado = RepositorioUsuario :: insertar_usuario(Conexion :: obtener_conexion(), $usuario);

        if ($usuario_insertado){
            //Redirigir al login

        }
    }

    Conexion :: cerrar_conexion();
}
```

Al fondo tengo un include_once el cual me redirige a otra conexion que si me funcionaba, si esta la borro no me funciona la anterior:

```
Conexion::abrir_conexion();

$total_usuarios = RepositorioUsuario::obtener_numero_usuario(Conexion::obtener_conexion());
echo $total_usuarios;

Conexion::cerrar_conexion();
```

Nose que me puede estar afectando a esta conexion.

Codigo Conexion:

```
class Conexion{
        private static $conexion;

        public static function abrir_conexion(){
            if(!isset(self::$conexion)){
                try{
                   include "config.inc.php";

                  
                    self::$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=".NOMBRE_SERVIDOR."; dbname=".NOMBRE_BD."; port=3307; charset=utf8", NOMBRE_USUARIO, PASSWORD);
                    self::$conexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    // Si ponemos lo siguiente comentado no funciona
                    //self::$conexion -> exec("SET CHARACTER utf8");
                }catch(PDOException $ex){
                    print "<db>"."ERROR: " . $ex -> getMessage() . "<br>";
                    die();
                }
            }
        }

        public static function cerrar_conexion(){
            if (isset(self::$conexion)){
                self::$conexion = null;
            }
        }

        // Para usar referencia a conexion fuera de esta clase ya que es privada
        public static function obtener_conexion(){
            return self::$conexion;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes definida la clase Conexion?

Comment: Además... revisa los espacios que tienes antes y después de `::`

Comment: He añadido el codigo de conexion, y los espacio de la clase no afecta, en la clas conexion del segundo codigo si que funciona, por eso no llego a entender el error.

Comment: De acuerdo, Ismael... lo que no sé es si la clase Conexion es accesible desde el primer tramo de código.  Dices que "al fondo" tienes un `include_once` que utiliza esa clase y sí funciona. Lo que no sé es si la definición de la clase está entre uno y otro código, o incluso si está llamado antes del 2º bloque de código

Comment: Tenias razon, no tenia definida la conexion en ese bloque, mucha gracias, ahora a otros errores jajaja